# Multiple forms using AJAX cause page to run too slowly

Tags: jquery, ajax, django

I am building a website in Django/python, and on this particular page, the view returns a set of objects. The template then generates a form for each object, and the form is submitted with AJAX.

Everything works as I want it to without errors, but the problem is the more objects that are in the view, the slower the AJAX works. With about 100 objects, it takes 2 to 3 seconds for each one, where with about 10 objects, it takes less than a second.

Originally I tried commenting out a lot of the things that happen on submission, but it didn't improve the speed at all!

I'm not sure how I can speed it up, without changing the way the code is organized, which I would like to stay away from, as is a feature I really like!

I have been searching but all answers are saying that it is the submission of the form that takes long, when that has made no difference to the speed of my code.

interact.html

```
{% for adopt in adopts %}
    <form class="interact-form">
        <!-- some fields -->
    </form>
{% endfor %}

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".interact-form").submit(function(){
        event.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
            url: '{% url 'interact' %}',
            type: 'POST',
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            context: this,
            success: function(data) {
                $(this).css("opacity", "0.3");
                $(this).css("cursor", "not-allowed");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

I am kind of new to Django and very new to AJAX and would really appreciate some help. The code is all very simple, but here it is (simplified) if that would help.

Comment: each AJAX call requires the overhead of its own headers and connections and a lot of other network information that most of us don't want to even think about. Besides being heavy for the browser, it probably is expensive for the server application to constantly be handling that level of requests. I don't know anything about django, but I think you should be able to abstract network transactions into its own layer that would compile a series of requests and send them all on intervals.

Comment: Thank you for the help! I'm honestly not sure I am advanced enough to work on something like that, but it's a good starting off point!

Comment: your ajax data will probably be mostly json encoded javascript objects, so you could make each "type" of data a property of the global one that would be sent off every 0.5 seconds or whatever. I haven't used ajax too extensively though, there might even be tools available for this

Answer (score 0):

I think that's because you are passing your `this` variable to your ajax `context` which has already a big content. So that's what I think is slowing your ajax, and also, the data type that being received also plays a big role in case of the speed (especially the html data). If I were you, I'd like to only accept `JSON` from the ajax url by using `dataType: 'json'` - which is the fastest DataType you can play with ajax.

```
$(".interact-form").submit(function(){
    event.preventDefault();
    var $this = $(this);
    $.ajax({
        url: '{% url 'interact' %}',
        type: 'POST',
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            // we are now expecting that `data` is a valid JSON object
            $this.css("opacity", "0.3");
            $this.css("cursor", "not-allowed");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I actually only just added the context, and it didn't seem to affect the speed. I also updated it to your suggestion and I haven't noticed a difference!